# Position of a line between two nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I don't understand how to use the command `(origin.220) -- (origin.220|-Destination.north)` in my code and therefore I'm have to guess when I'm going to put a line between two nodes. How can I determine what number I need to use (i.e 220) to put an edge from the bottom of the parent to the top of the child without interfering with other nodes? This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={
        rounded corners=1mm,
        align=center,
        font=\sffamily
    },
    main/.style={
        draw,
        text width=5cm
    }
}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Nodes
\node[main, label=180:(1)] (origen) {¿Se conoce la relacion confiabilidad/edad para esta falla?}; 

\node[main,anchor=east, label=180:(2)] (dos) at ($(origen.south)+(0,-1.5)$) {¿Es posible aplicar tareas TD?};
\node[main] (tareasTD) at ($(origen.south)+(-4,-3)$) {Especifique  tareas TD}; 

\node[main, label=180:(3)] (tres) at ($(origen.south)+(0,-4.5)$) {¿Es posible aplicar tareas CD?}; 
\node[main] (tareasCD) at ($(origen.south)+(-3,-6)$) {Especifique  tareas CD}; 

\node[main, text width=6cm,  label=180:(4)] (cuatro) at ($(origen.south)+(0,-7.5)$) {¿Es un modo de falla categoria D?}; 

\node[main, label=180:(5)] (cinco) at ($(origen.south)+(-3,-9)$) {¿Es posible aplicar tareas FF?}; 
\node[main] (tareasFF) at ($(origen.south)+(-4.5,-10.5)$) {Especifique  tareas FF}; 

\node[main, text width=6cm,  label=180:(6)] (efectivas) at ($(origen.south)+(0,-12)$) {¿Las tareas son efectivas?}; 

\node[main, text width=3.5cm, circle, anchor=west] (circ) at ($(origen.south east)+(0,-1.5)$) {Si esta relacion Puede ser determinada con analisis adicionales entonces asigne ... etc. };

% Edges
\draw (origen.220) -- (origen.220|-dos.north) node[midway, right] {Parcial};
\draw (origen.195) -- (origen.195|-dos.north) node[midway, left] {Sí};
\draw (dos.300) -- (dos.300|-tareasTD.north) node[midway, left] {Sí};
\draw (tareasTD.8) -- (tareasTD.8|-tres.north);
\draw (origen.340) -- (origen.340|-tres.north) node[pos=.2, right] {No};
\draw (dos.350) -- (dos.350|-tres.north) node[midway, right] {No};
\draw (tres.187) -- (tres.187|-tareasCD.north) node[midway, left] {Sí};
\draw (tres.340) -- (tres.340|-cuatro.north) node[midway, right] {No};
\draw (tareasCD.340) -- (tareasCD.340|-cuatro.north);
\draw (cuatro.187) -- (cuatro.187|-cinco.north) node[midway, left] {Sí};
\draw (cinco.195) -- (cinco.195|-tareasFF.north) node[midway, left] {Sí};
\draw (cinco.40) -- (cinco.40|-efectivas.north) node[midway, right] {No};

\draw[dashed] (circ.west) -- (circ.west-|origen.340);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And I want to fix the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any angle between 0 and 180 is above, and any angle from 180 to 360 is below, so if you set angles like `(cinco.40)` or `(tareasTD.8)`, the line will start from above.

Here's a GIF showing an example (the line starts from *origen*):

[image: figure 1]

### Output

[image: figure 2]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={
        rounded corners=1mm,
        align=center,
        font=\sffamily
    },
    main/.style={
        draw,
        text width=5cm
    }
}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Nodes
\node[main, label=180:(1)] (origen) {¿Se conoce la relacion confiabilidad/edad para esta falla?}; 

\node[main,anchor=east, label=180:(2)] (dos) at ($(origen.south)+(0,-1.5)$) {¿Es posible aplicar tareas TD?};
\node[main] (tareasTD) at ($(origen.south)+(-4,-3)$) {Especifique  tareas TD}; 

\node[main, label=180:(3)] (tres) at ($(origen.south)+(0,-4.5)$) {¿Es posible aplicar tareas CD?}; 
\node[main] (tareasCD) at ($(origen.south)+(-3,-6)$) {Especifique  tareas CD}; 

\node[main, text width=6cm,  label=180:(4)] (cuatro) at ($(origen.south)+(0,-7.5)$) {¿Es un modo de falla categoria D?}; 

\node[main, label=180:(5)] (cinco) at ($(origen.south)+(-3,-9)$) {¿Es posible aplicar tareas FF?}; 
\node[main] (tareasFF) at ($(origen.south)+(-4.5,-10.5)$) {Especifique  tareas FF}; 

\node[main, text width=6cm,  label=180:(6)] (efectivas) at ($(origen.south)+(0,-12)$) {¿Las tareas son efectivas?}; 

\node[main, text width=3.5cm, circle, anchor=west] (circ) at ($(origen.south east)+(0,-1.5)$) {Si esta relacion Puede ser determinada con analisis adicionales entonces asigne ... etc. };

% Edges
\draw (origen.220) -- (origen.220|-dos.north) node[midway, right] {Parcial};
\draw (origen.195) -- (origen.195|-dos.north) node[midway, left] {Sí};
\draw (dos.300) -- (dos.300|-tareasTD.north) node[midway, left] {Sí};
\draw (tareasTD.352) -- (tareasTD.352|-tres.north);
\draw (origen.340) -- (origen.340|-tres.north) node[pos=.2, right] {No};
\draw (dos.350) -- (dos.350|-tres.north) node[midway, right] {No};
\draw (tres.187) -- (tres.187|-tareasCD.north) node[midway, left] {Sí};
\draw (tres.340) -- (tres.340|-cuatro.north) node[midway, right] {No};
\draw (tareasCD.340) -- (tareasCD.340|-cuatro.north);
\draw (cuatro.187) -- (cuatro.187|-cinco.north) node[midway, left] {Sí};
\draw (cinco.195) -- (cinco.195|-tareasFF.north) node[midway, left] {Sí};
\draw (cinco.350) -- (cinco.350|-efectivas.north) node[midway, right] {No};

\draw[dashed] (circ.west) -- (circ.west-|origen.340);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @jd1215 No problem. I added a small gif showing you what angle does which. `0` and `180` are double because if you chose the above or the lower node, the line will start from the side like that (they are not simultaneous).

Comment: Thats great! how do you did the gif?

Comment: @jd1215 it's done with Latex + arara, a tool that among other things, creates a gif out of a pdf. It's all done with config files and a terminal command. :D